# What are the limitations of the data segment in the .exe file?

Tags: c++, c, assembly

In C++, if we hardcode a lot of data in the source file, what are the limitations? Can we hardcode an entire Lord of the Rings novel into our exe file?

PS: Yeah, I know it's bad programming practice but I just want to know the limitation.

Comment: In C++11 with raw strings, it isn't that tedious to manually put `\n`s after each lines. Simply copying and pasting would just work. :)

Comment: It's highly OS and executable-format dependent, and you haven't bothered to stipulate any.

Answer (score 0):

According to `IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER` structure, The limit for Windows EXE should be `0xffffffff`.

Comment: This article claims the limit is 2GB in a Windows executable: http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/memory-limits-applications-windows

Comment: @MichaelBurr, "Note that on 32-bit Windows, the sum of all types of data must be 2GB or less" - this is wrong, there is a 3GB flag... [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff556232(v=vs.85).aspx)